# Change the sort order with the dash being at the end of the query param

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Instead of sorting like this `/product/list/?sort=-price`, I wish to sort like this `/product/list/?sort=price-`, where the dash character is placed at the end of the field name in the query param.

In my views.py:

```py
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.db.models import F
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

from app.filters import ProductFilterSet
from app.models import Product
from app.serializers import ProductSerializer

class ProductViewSet(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,)
    filterset_class = ProductFilterSet
    ordering_fields = ("date_updated", "price")

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(date_updated=F("updated"))
```

And in `filters.py`:

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

from app.models import Product


class ProductFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {
            "category_id": ["exact"],
            "price": ["lt", "gt"],
            "is_available": ["exact"],
        }
```

I tried adding a custom ordering filter, like this:

```py
class CustomOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    def remove_invalid_fields(self, queryset, fields, view, request):
        # Remove the dash character from the end of the field name
        fields = [field.rstrip('-') for field in fields]
        return super().remove_invalid_fields(queryset, fields, view, request)

class ProductViewSet(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    pagination_class = ListPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, CustomOrderingFilter,)
    filterset_class = ProductFilterSet
    ordering_fields = ("date_updated", "price")

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(date_updated=F("updated"))
```

But it doesn't solve the problem and filtering with `sort=price-` doesn't have any effect on the result. How can I fix this?